# Array index out of bound exception

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

Actually i am scanning QR codes, if i pass full information to generate the QR and then scan it, it works fine, but if don't insert complete data to generate QR and then scan that QR, my app crashes. I have added the log report, and the code where it crashes. I have just inserted name and tel3 to generate QR, when i scanned it, it crashed

```
scanDataLength = scanData.length();
parts = scanData.split(":");                
semiColons = scanData.split(";");
qrCodeType = parts[0];
if (qrCodeType.contentEquals("MECARD")) {
    String name = semiColons[0].split(":")[2];
    String adr = semiColons[1].split(":")[1];
    String tel = semiColons[2].split(":")[1];
    String tel2 = semiColons[3].split(":")[1];
    String tel3 = semiColons[4].split(":")[1];
    String email = semiColons[5].split(":")[1];
    String email2 = semiColons[6].split(":")[1];
    String url = semiColons[7].split(":")[1];
    String notes = semiColons[8].split(":")[1];
    saveContact(name, adre, tel, tel2, tel3, email, email2, url, notes);
}
```

Log

```
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at com.gravity.innovations.qr.manager.ScanQRActivity$2.onPreviewFrame(ScanQRActivity.java:299)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:786)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-17 14:46:04.369: E/AndroidRuntime(12417):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 14:46:05.588: I/Process(12417): Sending signal. PID: 12417 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `scanData` example would be great.
The problem probably is here:
`String name = semiColons[0].split(":")[2];`.
Change the value `[2]` to `[1]`

Comment: I changed it to .split(":")[1] and i am getting the same error on the String tel = semiColons[2].split(":")[1]; as i didn't inserted address while generating QR

Answer (score 0):

```
.split(":")[2];
```

and

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
```

So, you have just 0, and 1 as valid indexes

Comment: what should i do? I changed it to .split(":")[1] and i am getting the same error on the String tel = semiColons[2].split(":")[1];

Comment: you should check the array's size. You can access only the positions between 0 and size - 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related your Array length

```
String name = semiColons[0].split(":")[2];
```

There is no 2 column in your semiColons[0] row so you need to fix that by adding something after the ":" or by changing the index from 2 to 1 or 0